# Dagger injection not working in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

Someone helps me to point out that why my code does not work. I try to figure out but I cannot find out the problem
I try to inject presenter but I got the error:

```
lateinit property appComponent has not been initialized
```

It seems that the presenter has been not injected
AppModule

```
@Module
class AppModule {
    @Provides @Singleton
    fun provideMainPresenter():  MainActivityContract.Presenter = MainActivityPresenter()
}
```

AppComponent

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(AppModule::class))
interface AppComponent {

    fun inject(target: MainActivity)

}
```

App

```
class App: Application() {

    companion object {
        lateinit var  appComponent: AppComponent
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        appComponent = initDagger()
    }

    fun initDagger() = DaggerAppComponent.create()
}
```

This is the MainActivity where I want inject presenter to

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MainActivityContract.View, AnkoLogger {

    @Inject
    lateinit var presenter:  MainActivityContract.Presenter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        App.appComponent.inject(this)
        presenter.attachView(this) 
    }

}
```

This is MainActivityPresenter which implements MainActivityContract.Presenter

```
class MainActivityPresenter: MainActivityContract.Presenter {
    var view: MainActivityContract.View? = null

    override fun attachView(view: MainActivityContract.View) {
        this.view = view
    }

    override fun detachView() {
        view = null
    }

    override fun performToast(text: String) {
    }

}
```

**Edit:** I managed to solve it myself:
For all android beginner as I am. When we declare App extends Application. We must declare it in manifest as well

```
<application
        android:name=".App"
/>
```

Comment: what kind of error?

Comment: why is not working? please add the error stack trace or something...

Comment: Update my question. Retrofit could not provide presenter

Comment: @trnahaminh please add your solution as an Answer instead of editing your original question.

Comment: what a legend - thanks for fix

Answer (score 1):

In the MainActivity, you can replace the code:

```
@Inject
lateinit var presenter:  MainActivityContract.Presenter
```

for

```
@field:[Inject]
lateinit var presenter: MainActivityContract.Presenter
```

Comment: Can you please explain why? I have seen many other using @Inject

Comment: It does not work

Answer (score 0):

You can't define a static variable as a `lateinit` and expect `onCreate()` to initialize it. Try something like this:

```
class GlobalApplication : Application() {
    companion object {
        lateinit var globalApp: GlobalApplication
    }

    internal var mApplicationComponent: ApplicationComponent? = null
        get

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        globalApp = this

        //Init Timber
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())
        }

        //Init application component
        mApplicationComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                .applicationModule(ApplicationModule(this))
                .build()

        mApplicationComponent?.inject(this)

        //Ignore URI exposure
        val builder = StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build())
    }
}
```

Taken from this project: https://github.com/Obaied/Sohan/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/obaied/sohan/GlobalApplication.kt